# How to open two terminals side by side using `screen`

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I use vim a lot. I can open two files side by side with `-O` option:

```
$ vim -O hello.{h,cpp}
```

Today I tried `screen`:

```
`C-a |`      => split terminal vertically.
`C-a <tab>`  => switch to the new `region`
`C-a c`      => run bash in this `region`
```

Can I create two terminals side by side like `vim -O` with one-line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this to happen every time you run screen, you can put the following in `~/.screenrc`:

```
vert_split
screen
focus
screen
```

Otherwise, you can create a new file with these commands, and pass it as a configuration file, eg:

```
screen -c ~/.splitscreenrc
```